# How to free image cache/memory in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, out-of-memory, arrays

In my Windows Phone 8 application I have a page with a `LongListSelector` which is bound to a list of 1000 objects having a property for `base64string` for image. Now to display the image, I wrote this converter to convert the `bas64string` into a `stream`.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,  System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (!value.ToString().Contains("http://"))
    {
        string str = value.ToString();
        byte[] bytes = Converter.FromBase64String(str);

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
            image.SetSource(stream); 
            bytes = null;
            var memoryusage = string.Format("Memory: {0} bytes", 
            DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage"));
            Debug.WriteLine(memoryusage);
            return image;
        }
    }
    else
    { 
        return null;
    }
}
```

And this is the memoryusage:

```
    Memory: 92549120 bytes
    Memory: 92946432 bytes
    Memory: 92946432 bytes
    Memory: 92946432 bytes
    Memory: 92946432 bytes
    Memory: 93192192 bytes
    Memory: 93192192 bytes
    Memory: 96079872 bytes
    Memory: 100700160 bytes
    Memory: 100700160 bytes
    Memory: 109568000 bytes
    Memory: 111734784 bytes
    Memory: 142852096 bytes
    Memory: 143056896 bytes
    Memory: 143056896 bytes
    Memory: 143261696 bytes
    Memory: 140791808 bytes
    Memory: 141103104 bytes
    Memory: 141529088 bytes
    Memory: 142151680 bytes
    Memory: 146784256 bytes
    Memory: 146784256 bytes
    Memory: 155066368 bytes
    Memory: 156368896 bytes
```

At memory equals to or maybe some bytes greater than this 156368896 bytes, the application crashes with the `EngineExecutionException`. Once I got "OutOfMemoryException for this:

```
image.SetSource(stream);
```

Obviously this is a memory issue. I need to clear image cache memory but how? I see the link in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12267163/1949475, but I'm unable to use it.

Note: not all images are displayed at the same time, and the application takes this much memory after I go back and come back to the page again changing the data to be displayed in the LongListSelector.

Comment: Do you *Dispose* the images returned from `Convert` somewhere?

Comment: No....images are returned to Image element in xaml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is important to set in your converter class

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(); 
image.DecodePixelType = DecodePixelType.Logical; 
image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.BackgroundCreation; 
image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation; 
image.DecodePixelWidth = 56; 
image.DecodePixelHeight = 100;
```

Comment: Can you please help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24157246/wp8-out-of-memory-error-while-loading-images

Comment: Isn't this a temporary solution? I mean you are reducing the memory consumed by a bitmap image, but wont this problem arise if I load very large number of images.